# 'export default' on webstorm 2017.2.5 for React App + JSX

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webstorm, atom-editor, jsx

/*Greetings to all; I would like some help as regards an issue i am having with the 'export default' module on Webstorm when building react apps.

Background to recreate issue:
After going through the steps to create a React app: [1]:   npm install -g create-react-app   [2]: create-react-app hello_world  [3]: cd hello_world   [4] npm start

//Everything works fine.
*/
- Open the project Folder in Webstorm 2017.2.5
- Navigate to the src folder and open the App.js file
- Observe the last line of code: 'export default App' //All is active 
  and working. Implies, JSX syntax is enabled in ES6.
- create a new JS file inside the same src folder and fill in with the 
  following (just something quick to test. classNames used are just for demo):

```
1   import React, { Component } from 'react';
2   import logo from './logo.svg';
3   import './App.css';

4    class Output extends Component {
5        render() {
6            return (
7                <div className="output">
8                    <header className="output-header">
9                        <img src={logo} className="output-logo" alt="logo" />
10                           <h3 className="output-title">Welcome to React</h3>
11                    </header>
12                    <p className="output-intro">
13                        To get started, edit <code>src/Output.js</code> and 
                          save to reload.
14                    </p>
15                </div>
16            );
17        }
18    }
19    export default Output; // this is where I am having the challenge. 
  Webstorms error highlighting says: 'Unused default export'
```

- I tried to import the Output.js file into the App.js file via: 
  `import Output from './Output';` //yet the problem persists.
- I also tried doing the same with another Editor (Atom), and it worked perfectly. problem was solved.
- After looking up this issue, I came across something similar [here][1] but no solution.

How can I resolve this issue on Webstorm?

Comment: Link of the similar problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28187

Comment: Have you tried to add `.jsx` to the import?
So like `import Output from '.Output.jsx'`.

Comment: can't recreate using similar example in 2017.5. Can you check if invalidating caches (File | Invalidate caches, Restart) fixes the issue?

Comment: @Lando  Thanks for the response. I did try adding the files with the . jsx extension and yet the issue persisted.

Comment: @Lena, thanks for the response. Yea. This solves the issue in some way. Each time I created a new .js or .jsx file and tried to import it, the problem persisted. however, after invalidating the cache and restarting the IDE, it was cleared up. I guess its more of a sync issue. but the latency is quite high in comparison to what the Atom Editor provides.

Comment: it shouldn't normally happen. I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing your idea.log and steps to repeat

Comment: @Lando-L Problem solved. I think its more of a warning than an Error. Webstorm expects all export calls, should be followed by the appropraite import. AND also it has to be used in the main App component.

Comment: @Lena Problem solved. Its more of a warning than an Error. Webstorm expects all export calls, should be followed by the appropraite import. AND also it has to be used in the main App component. – This clears the warning.